# Playwright not displaying exception when locator not exists in DOM

Tags: exception, playwright

I am new to Playwright, I am trying to implement Playwritght +NUnit framework.
I currently facing 2 issues,

a. When I have give any invalid locator (eg: xpath, cssselector), Playwright not throwing exception message, it's continue next step, even I try in try/catch block it not print exception.

```
    _page.Locator("input#email1234").ClickAsync();
```

I have tried following code still it not displaying any error.

```
await _page.Locator("input#email1234").ClickAsync(new LocatorClickOptions() { Trial = true });
```

b. I have used the waitForAsync conditions with 60sec, but playwright not wait until 60sec
to visible the locator in DOM, it's continue to next step, if I execute the script in debig mode and wait for 60sec then it displaying exception. Otherwise it continue to next step and  closing the browser before display exception and test got passed.

```
await GetElement(_page, "input#email").WaitForAsync(new()
   { State = WaitForSelectorState.Visible, Timeout =60000 });
```

Can someone please help me how address above issues.
Appreciate your help.

thanks
Rag

Answer (score 0):

Option A with an `await` should work for you. Your code is not failing because we are not awaiting for the action that might fail.

```
await _page.Locator("input#email1234").ClickAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you Hardkoded,

I have added await before that ClickAsync() method but still same issue, it's not displaying any exception.